# Trouble - I see websites differently than others - DPI?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, resolution, dpi

I have troubles displaying different elements on my PC. Obviously my PC renders websites differently than other PCs in our office. This is huge problem for me since my programming and desing isn't correct therefore.

I use Windows 8.1, my primary browser is Chrome, but I also checked Firefox and IE. My monitors are two full HD Benq's. Tried to reset all display settings, resolution, DPI, font-sizing and smoothening. Nothing works so far.

Take a look at screenshots from my colleague's PC (left) and mine:

[image]

**[Larger image here](http://data.atria.sk/monitors.jpg)**

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

#### I have troubles displaying different elements on my PC.

It looks even worse here in the latest Firefox.

[image]

I would start by fixing the errors on your site.

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atria.sk%2F:

```
Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!
Result: 83 Errors, 11 warning(s)
```

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atria.sk%2F

```
W3C CSS Validator results for http://www.atria.sk/ (CSS level 3)
Sorry! We found the following errors (73) (and 290 warnings)
```

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atria.sk%2F

```
W3C CSS Validator results for http://www.atria.sk/ (CSS level 2.1)
Sorry! We found the following errors (450) (and 270 warnings)
```